# REST API testing from command line with a nice report

Tags: validation, rest, testing, report, jsonschema

I wonder if there is any tool that will allow me to:

- test REST API responses (JSON schema validation, correct codes returned)
- generate a nice ready-to-read report from testing that will clearly show if (and what) there's something wrong with replies returned

Does anyone know such tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at [Frisby.js](http://frisbyjs.com/) -- it validates both headers and bodies, and has a JUnit compatible output option that you can use for reports (e.g. in Jenkins or another CI system).

See the [documentation](http://frisbyjs.com/docs/api/) for details.

If you want to validate against JSON Schema, you may be able to combine that with the jsonschema npm module.